# Need to Restart an Excel VBA Do...Until Loop

Tags: excel, vba

Here's the code about which I will seek assistance:

```
For i = 1 To numPlayers
    replacementDone = 0
    Do Until replacementDone <> 0
        replaceCards = InputBox("blah...blah")
        If replaceCards <> 0 Then
            replace100 = Application.Round((replaceCards / 100), 0)
            If replace100 < 5 Then
                Players(i, replace100) = Deck(DeckIndex)
                DeckIndex = DeckIndex + 1
            Else
                MsgBox "Invalid entry - try again."
            End If
            replace10 = Application.Round(Application.Mod(replaceCards, 100) / 10, 0)
            If replace10 < 5 And replace10 > replace100 Then
                Players(i, replace10) = Deck(DeckIndex)
                DeckIndex = DeckIndex + 1
            Else
                MsgBox "Invalid entry - try again."
            End If
            replace1 = Application.Round(Application.Mod(replaceCards, 10), 0)
            If replace1 < 5 And replace1 > replace10 Then
                Players(i, replace1) = Deck(DeckIndex)
                DeckIndex = DeckIndex + 1
            Else
                MsgBox "Invalid entry - try again."
            End If
        End If
    Loop
Next i
```

At each point where an `If` statement is untrue and the `MsgBox "Invalid entry - try again."` is to appear, I want to restart the `Do Until` loop.  All responses I've seen regarding restarting a `Do Until` loop address the user's code logic rather than identifying how to do the restart.  Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: _All responses I've seen regarding restarting a Do Until loop address the user's code logic rather than identifying how to do the restart_  that's because wanting to restart the loop is a clear sign of flawed logic!  I suggest you address the real issue rather than try to bandaid bad code.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, I understand and agree completely.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a "goto" statement, like so:

```
For i = 1 To numPlayers
    replacementDone = 0

    LoopStart:
    Do Until replacementDone <> 0
        replaceCards = InputBox("blah...blah")
        If replaceCards <> 0 Then
            replace100 = Application.Round((replaceCards / 100), 0)
            If replace100 < 5 Then
                Players(i, replace100) = Deck(DeckIndex)
                DeckIndex = DeckIndex + 1
            Else
                MsgBox "Invalid entry - try again."
                GoTo LoopStart
            End If
            replace10 = Application.Round(Application.Mod(replaceCards, 100) / 10, 0)
            If replace10 < 5 And replace10 > replace100 Then
                Players(i, replace10) = Deck(DeckIndex)
                DeckIndex = DeckIndex + 1
            Else
                MsgBox "Invalid entry - try again."
                GoTo LoopStart
            End If
            replace1 = Application.Round(Application.Mod(replaceCards, 10), 0)
            If replace1 < 5 And replace1 > replace10 Then
                Players(i, replace1) = Deck(DeckIndex)
                DeckIndex = DeckIndex + 1
            Else
                MsgBox "Invalid entry - try again."
                GoTo LoopStart
            End If
        End If
    Loop
Next i
```

Comment: I've tried to avoid GoTo, but in this case it's the simplest solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Completely agree, sometimes you have to accept an answer that may not be ideal to get moving on to the next part of your project.  Perhaps flag that section with a note to refactor when you can dive in a bit deeper as @chris-neilsen suggested in his comments.